# Django custom url structure

Tags: django, django-urls

Is there any built-in or 3rd party app for custom styled urls?

I'd like to have custom urls such as:
`example.com/article-type/article-name-2015-24-12`

Where article-type would be a created from a foreign key and at the end of the url there would be the published date.

And in templates I'd call them using `{% url 'article' article.pk %}`. (So in the future when my boss decides to change the url structure I don't have to change it everywhere)

Is there anything like that? If not could anyone kick me to the right direction how to implement a such feature?

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding what you want - you can do this with just Django urls. But instead of `{% url 'article' article.pk %}` it would be something like `{% url 'article' article.name article.date %}` or better yet, have a slug on the `Article` model and make sure it is unique then you can just use the slug as such `{% url 'article' article.slug %}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build the URL on the model, overriding [the `get_absolute_url()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url).

Something like this

```
def Something(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    article_type = models.ForeignKey(ArticleTypes)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '/{}/{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(
            self.article_type, self.slug, self.created.year, 
            self.created.month, self.created.day)
```

And in the template, you'd use

```
<a href="{{ something.get_absolute_url }}">{{ something.name }}</a>
```